# find points close to targets, but at least min_dist apart

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Given a number of target points $t_1,\dots,t_n\in\mathbb{R}$, I would like to find matching $x_i$ such that they are as close as possible to their $t_i$ partner, but at least $a>0$ apart. In math:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_i (x_i - t_i)^2 \to \min_x,\\
(x_i - x_j)^2 \ge a^2 \quad \forall i,j.
$$
How to best solve this? (Solutions that are easily implementable in Python preferred.)

Comment: General constraint OLS.

Comment: If you just need to calculate a set of solutions instead of understanding the underlying theory, you can just use the CVXOPT package for Python. It's fairly easy to use and is pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to convert it to a problem with non-negativity constraints. For this, make sure that the $x_i$ are sorted and use the variables
$$
\begin{split}
\tilde{x}_0 &= x_0 - x_0^{\text{min}}\\
d_i &= x_i - x_{i-1} - a
\end{split}
$$
and note that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_i (x_i - t_i)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \left(\tilde{x}_0 + \sum_{j=1}^i d_j - (t_i - i a - x_0^{\text{min}})\right)^2.
$$
This can be treated with a non-negative least-squares solver (e.g., [from scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html)); the system matrix $A$ will be lower triangular.